# textfield with link

Tags: javascript, extjs

as I can get my textfield displays the contents as `<a>`?

```
items: [{
  xtype: 'textfield',
  value: '<a href="www.google.com"> www.google.com </a>' <--
}]
```

Comment: Please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want your text input to be clickable, as if it were an `<a>` tag?  That seems kind-of problematic.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that with textfield or textarea.  If you only want the link, the following works:

```
                    fieldLabel: 'Attention',
                html: '<a href="http://google.com">xxxxxxxxxxx</a>',
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript, you can do something like this:

HTML

```
<label for="txt">Text</label>
<input id="txt" type="text" onclick="url=document.getElementById('txt').value;if (url != ''){window.location=url;}"/>
```

CSS

```
input#txt {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Find it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YRawg/24/)